# Modify code for functions.php with specific twitter user url and hashtags

Tags: plugin-development, functions, twitter

I am looking to import Tweets with certain hashtags and came across this great response and coding in the link below. My question is how to just get posts from one particular twitter user and will the code in the link below be customized for multiple hashtags. If someone can offer advise on where to modify the coding to add to functions.php with the specific user url would be much appreciated. I familiar with php and wordpress but still learning all the details. Thanks again!!

Cheers!

[Importing Tweets with certain hashtags into Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9447/importing-tweets-with-certain-hashtags-into-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

The request to Twitter API in that code is formulated as URL. It is easy enough to modify it.

- see [GET search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) in Twitter API documentation
- see [advanced search](http://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced) for formulating queries

Then put resulting query in request. Use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) or related functions to encode spaces and such properly.